# XML path for specific element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am looking for xpath for **externalControlNumber** with value before hyphen "-", in this below example it would be **47069**.

I tried this /Message but it is giving me complete value in Message and /Message@externalControlNumber doesn't work.

Any help on how can I drive only specific value for

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Message externalControlNumber="47069-1580883967886" externalVersion="2.6" language="en" 
  messageType="Production" mlxmlVersion="2.6" protocol="XML" timestamp="1582613693264">

  </Message>
```

Answer (score 1):

substring-before(/Message/@externalControlNumber, '-')

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a /.

```
/Message/@externalControlNumber
```

Comment: Thank you. I was specifically looking for value before -.
Did few more googling and found substring-before(/Message/@externalControlNumber, '-')

Comment: Oops, I actually did what you found when I tried it out, but thought that the missing / was your problem :)